# PopOver button disappears when I switch page on UISplitView application

Tags: xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, ipad

I am trying to make a application that uses the standard Split View Application in Xcode, i want to be able to have multiple detail view controllers, this is all set up and it switches between the different detail view controllers fine, although when it switches it doesn't show the popup view controller button in the top left hand corner when i switch to a new page

Many Thanks for any Help
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fund that the reason that this may occur is because the default Xcode uiSplitView application template sets the detail view as the split view delegate so you need to either make the master view to be the delegate or make the new detail view as a delegate also.